# Quenching for a long cylinder in matlab using besels function

Tags: matlab, bessel-functions

Supposedly a cylinder is heated to very high temperature and is quenched into a quenchant where the surrounding temperature is at non zero temperature i.e., T0 and initial temperature of cylinder is Ti.

The equation  is to find out the temperature of a point anywhere between surface and center at a given time t, for a given thermal conductivity and heat transfer coefficient.

```
T(r,t)=T0+2/b(Ti-T0)* summation of (1/beta(m))*(J1(beta(m)*b)*J0(beta(m)*r))/(J0 square(beta(m)*b)+J1 square(beta(m)*b))* exp-(beta(m) square *alpha* t)  where summation is m=1 to infinity.
```

J0 is the bessels function of first kind and J1=-d(J0)/dz

Where the eigen values beta(m) are obtained from the roots of transcendental equation

```
beta*b*J1(beta*b)-Bi*J0(beta*b)=0 where Bi is the biot number.
```

How do I draw a cooling curve using the above equation?

I'm new to matlab and this is completely out of my league. I have seen nothing like this in any other questions. Thanks for any help.

Comment: First, what exactly do you have a problem with here? Is the problem to generate a numerical solution to the 3 dimensional heat equation? In that case, I would would recommend [maths.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Secondly, this problem is not matlab specific, meaning that the problem can be solved in more or less the same way using any programming language and proper libraries. The biggest difference (syntax wise) is that matlab can handle a lot of vector operations, making the syntaxes similar to maths. This leads to the question have you programmed before at all.

Comment: Not trying to be rude or so. It is just that I wonder what part of the problem the problem is. Do you know how to solve this in theory using some (selected) numerical method? Meaning, do you have an implementable algorithm on paper which you want to write in code, but does not know how? Or is the problem that you does not know how to solve this problem with a numerical solution? The latter problem is harder and belongs to math stack exchange.